# Return data from C++ exe to web

Tags: php, c++, web-services, exe

I have a program that reads some input files, and creates a (very large) output file.

Now i have to upload this program to the web. it is written on php and server is on linux.

The server calls 'exec' function to operate the exe file of my program and it should then return to the user a link to download the output file.
since there might be several output files, i call each output file in a different name (output_*seconds from latest new year*).

What i need to do now, is somehow tell the server what output file the clients should get.
I thought that maybe i should return from main the integer that is part of the name of the file,
for example i could return from main 340000, and then the server knows the file's name is "output_340000". but im not sure if that's such a good idea, and i also don't know how to get that integer.

Another thing came to my mind, is to print the name of the file to the console, but then i don't how the sever would read this, and also i don't know if it would work after the program exits.

so my question is basically, how to return the name of the output file to the server?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify are you able to change the source code of the PHP and C++ file? For example, is it an option to change the output of the C++ program?

Comment: Yes, i am able to change source codes.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `exec` from php with multiple arguments. If you pass a variable for the second argument, the exectuable's console output will be saved in it. You can just output the filename with `printf` or `cout` if the executable doesn't print anything else.

If you want to go the second route of returning an integer from main, pass three variables to `exec` and the third will contain the status code of the process you exec'd.

You can read about the other options for exec in the [PHP Reference Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: thank you for the helpful answer, i decided to "invent" the output file name in the php code and send it as an argument to the program. (i print other things to the console so the console way is difficult).

Comment: @flyman You're welcome. Hopefully knowing this will help you in the future.

Comment: @flyman Have you given thought to what you plan to do with the files after they are no longer necessary?